# google colab tensorflow-io audio error undefined symbol in system library?

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pip, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to open audio files in Google Colab using the TensorFlow library, I'm following [this example](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/audio) from their wiki.

pip installs the package just fine but then the function call to

```py
audio = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor('gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac')
```

With the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io.so, from paths: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so']
caused by: ['/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK10tensorflow4data11DatasetBase8FinalizeEPNS_15OpKernelContextESt8functionIFN3tsl8StatusOrINS5_4core11RefCountPtrIS1_EEEEvEE']
```

I've checked out trough `ls` and `objdump` and the .so file is present, it seems the problem is with function `_ZNK10tensorflow4data11DatasetBase8FinalizeEPNS_15OpKernelContextESt8functionIFN3tsl8StatusOrINS5_4core11RefCountPtrIS1_EEEEvEE`

Why?

I've tried to re-install the libraries and change the backed from CPU to T4 GPU to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy, here's the fix

```bash
!pip install tensorflow==2.10.0 tensorflow-io==0.27.0
```

maybe `tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor` is not available in the latest version